# EOF error in python in codechef problem's solution

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I have written a code for a problem on code chef, the code runs  well on  PYCHARM ide and also when I use custom input in the code chef ide but after submission it gives compillation error.

```
def win(n):
    goals=list(map(int,input().split()))
    fouls=list(map(int,input().split()))
    goal=[i*20 for i in goals]
    foul=[j*(-10) for j in fouls]
    for i in range(len(goals)):
        p=goal[i]+foul[i]
        if p<0:
            p==0
            points.append(p)
        else:
            points.append(p)
    return max(points)


t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    k=int(input())
    x=win(k)
    print(x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 16, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some errors in the code...

```
def win(n):
goals=list(map(int,input().split()))
fouls=list(map(int,input().split()))
goal=[i*20 for i in goals]
foul=[j*(-10) for j in fouls]
points=[]
for i in range(len(goals)):
    p=goal[i]+foul[i]
    if p<0:
        p=0
        points.append(p)
    else:
        points.append(p)
return max(points)


t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    k=int(input())
    x=win(k)
    print(x)
```

Comment: but, it gets succesfully excuted  in custom input